# Let $B=\{[a,b)\subset\Bbb R\mid a,b\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }a<b\}$ Show that $B$ is basis for topology on $\Bbb R$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Let $B=\{[a,b)\subset\Bbb R\mid a,b\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }a<b\}$ Show that $B$ is basis for topology on $\Bbb R$.

please check my proof

1.Let $\bigcup B=\Bbb R$ and $x\in\Bbb Q $ then $x\in [x,x+1)$ and $[x,x+1)\in B$

2.Let $B_{1}=[a,b)a,b\in\Bbb Q$ and $B_{2}=[c,d)c,d\in\Bbb Q$

and

$a\leq c\leq d\leq b$ and $x\in B_{1}\cap B_{2}$

It must exist interval $B_{3}=[e,f) e,f\in\Bbb Q$

that lie between $a\leq c\leq d\leq b$

therefore $x\in B_{3}\subseteq B_{1}\cap B_{2}$ and $B$ is basis for a topology on $\Bbb R$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give an idea of a more valid proof:
Let $\mathcal{B} = \{[a,b): a,b \in \mathbb{Q}, a < b\}$ be our candidate base.

1. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. As the rationals are order dense in the reals we can find some $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x-1 < q < x$. But then $x \in [q,q+1)$ and $[q,q+1) \in \mathcal{B}$, so $\bigcup \mathcal{B} = \mathbb{R}$.
2. Let $B_1= [a,b) \in \mathcal{B}$ and $B_2 = [c,d) \in \mathcal{B}$.
   Let $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ be arbitrary. Then we know that $a \le x < b$ and $c \le x < d$ so that $\max(a,c) \le x$ and $x < \min(b,d)$. As all of $a,b,c,d$ are in $\mathbb{Q}$, $[\max(a,c),\min(b,d)) \in \mathcal{B}$ as well and clearly $$x \in [\max(a,c),\min(b,d)) \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$$ as required.

So $\mathcal{B}$ obeys the two conditions to generate a topology.

Answer (score 8):

Your proof is not a proof at all. If you wrote down this proof in an exam and I was correcting it, I would give you a point or two out of 25 for having some correct ideas, but no more. It is entirely unclear (1) what you are proving, (2) what you are assuming and (3) what statement follows from what other statement.

For example, you begin your proof by saying

> Let $\bigcup B=\mathbb R$ and $x\in \mathbb Q$.

But you cannot just say "let this thing be true", if "this thing" is exactly what you want to **prove**! You have to **prove** that $\bigcup B=\mathbb R$. To do that, you need to prove that every element $x\in\mathbb R$ is an element of $\bigcup B$. Therefore, your proof should start with the words:

> Let $x\in\mathbb R$.

and conclude with

> Therefore, $x\in\bigcup B$.

---

Similarly, for point $2$, your proof should start with two arbitrary elements $B_1,B_2\in B$, and an element $x\in B_1\cap B_2$. Your proof should conclude with the discovery of $B^*\in B$ (or whatever else you want to call the set) such that $x\in B^*\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$

Comment: A clear and useful critique of the OP's attempt, in my opinion. +1

Comment: @Brahadeesh Thanks. I think OP has the right ideas in mind, but also suffers from a clearly "new to mathematical rigor" syndrome. We've all been there, confronted for the first time with a strict demand that we write down only what we know or know to assert. It's a tough first climb for most...

Comment: thank for comment It's useful for me

Comment: Absolutely. I don't think this answer is judgemental at all. I remember my own struggles all too well, in fact. :)